# Can the intersection of two regular languages be non-regular?

Tags: state, automata

Can the intersection of two regular languages be non-regular?

Can you give me examples to when this might occur?

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: Its not i was looking at an example where the union of 2 regular languages are not always regular so was wondering how it may occur for an intersection

Comment: The union and intersection of two regular languages are both always regular. This can be shown by considering mechanisms to form union and intersection DFAs from two original DFAs.

Answer (score 2):

No, the intersection of two regular languages is guaranteed to be a regular language. This can be proved a lot of ways, but an easy way is to use closure properties. Suppose you have regular languages L1 and L2. There are DFAs M1 and M2 for these languages. Change all accepting states to non-accepting and vice versa in both machines; call the resulting machines M1' and M2'. These accept the complements of L1 and L2, which must be regular languages (since there are DFAs that accept them). Because these complements are regular, there are regular expressions r1 and r2 for them. Then the regular expression r = r1 + r2 also describes a regular language. Therefore, it has a DFA M. Change all accepting states to non-accepting states and vice versa in M to get M'. M' now accepts the regular language (L1' union L2')'. But we know by De Morgan that this expression is equivalent to L1 intersect L2.

This is a constructive proof in that it shows you how to build a DFA for L1 intersect L2 given DFAs for L1 and L2. Other constructive proofs are possible. Another popular option is by using the Cartesian product machine construction. This would yield a DFA with one state for every pair of states in L1 and L2, and the transitions would correspond to pairs of transitions taken from L1 and L2.